# Jquery UI Sortable multiple items almost working but one remaining issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have two connected sortables, dragging between these works fine. I needed to drag more than one at a time, so I got that working using the following like, appending selected items to event.item.

```
$(this).sortable({
         connectWith: ".stage-content",
         placeholder: 'placeholder',
         start: function(ui, e) {
             e.item.siblings(".selected").appendTo(e.item);
....
```

The problem I can't figure out, when not hovering over one of the two drop zones, the placeholder ends up within the elements I am dragging. If you let go at this time, they disappear.

**HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy**

Which makes perfect sense, but I do not know what the solution is, any help is appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/mstefanko/kxBUG/

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom is the jsfiddle with an example. Hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                 $(".droppable").droppable({
                    drop: function(event, ui) {
                        var $list = $(this);
                        $helper = ui.helper;
                        $($helper).removeClass("selected");
                        var $selected = $(".selected");                 
                        if($selected.length > 1){                       
                            moveSelected($list,$selected);
                        }else{
                            moveItem(ui.draggable,$list);
                        }                                       
                    }, tolerance: "touch"
                 });

                 $(".draggable").draggable({
                    revert: "invalid",
                    helper: "clone",
                    cursor: "move",
                    drag: function(event,ui){
                        var $helper = ui.helper;
                        $($helper).removeClass("selected");
                        var $selected = $(".selected"); 
                        if($selected.length > 1){   
                            $($helper).html($selected.length + " items");
                        }                                       
                    }
                 });

                function moveSelected($list,$selected){
                    $($selected).each(function(){
                        $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                            $(this).appendTo($list).removeClass("selected").fadeIn();
                        });                 
                    });             
                }

                function moveItem( $item,$list ) {
                    $item.fadeOut(function() {
                        $item.find(".item").remove();
                        $item.appendTo( $list ).fadeIn();
                    });
                }

                $(".item").click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
                });

            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/caferdo/k5XJv/3/

Answer (score 0):

You should add `$(YOUR SORTABLE OBJECT).sortable( "refresh" )` in start function.

```
$(this).sortable({
         connectWith: ".stage-content",
         placeholder: 'placeholder',
         start: function(ui, e) {
             e.item.siblings(".selected").appendTo(e.item);
             $(YOUR SORTABLE OBJECT).sortable( "refresh" );}
...
```