# Drag all the items of Jquery Sortable together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable to drag and drop item in between three list as shown below.
    In some scenarios i need to move all the items from one list to another.I went through few links in stackoverflow but couldn't  make it work.
    so looking for some help.

```
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable"            
    }).disableSelection();
```

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your call.  First, you declare a class for tying the lists together, but never use that class to actually tie them together.  Instead, your html should look like this, with the `class="connectedSortable"` added:

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable3" class="connectedSortable">
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
</ul>
```

Second, you also have an option in there to prevent the last item of any list from being dragged, so you need to remove the cancel option if you would like to remove all items from a list, like so:

```
jQuery( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
}).disableSelection();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/R4U9F/

Comment: Thanks for information.I updated class name for each ul item and one item validation i already removed before you posted :)

Comment: So is there another issue because that should work fine now, as in the fiddle?

Comment: actually i would like to move all the list items from one ul to another ul using drag drop instead of drag and drop one by one.

Comment: In my application i have two scenarios.                                1.drop list item one by one 2.drop all the item from one <ul> to another in one shot

Comment: I see.  Your question is not very clear.  You might want to take a look here as this has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696821/jquery-ui-sortable-multiple-items-almost-working-but-one-remaining-issue